# Can You Decorate a Black Box?

Tags: design-patterns, decorator, black-box

I have a quick, very uninformed question about the Decorator pattern. If I have a class called BlackBox that I cannot edit in any way - can't add an interface, can't make any of the methods virtual, etc. - can this object be decorated using the Decorator pattern? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a wrapper for it (i.e., implement the [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern) and decorate the adapter.